# Где находится код функции import python?

Tags: python

Хотел бы посмотреть исходный код самой функции import... хочу посмотреть тоесть как он работает изнутри, подскажите как найти этот код...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`import` - это не функция, а ключевое слово (оператор) языка Python.

Посмотреть исходный код (на языке С) можно [здесь](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/import.c).

Объяснение работы - [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужна именно *функция*, то есть встроенная функция `__import__` для импортирования модулей:

```py
>>> math = __import__('math')
>>> math.pow(2, 3)
8.0
```

Её исходный код можно найти по ссылке https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c#L272

Comment: И вам спасибо большое